# Entity Framework - Unable to create a constant value of type x. Only primitive types are supported in this context.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following

A Engineer Model:

```
public class engineers
{
    public Guid? Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I fill the a list of engineers with the correct details:

```
List<engineers> listeng = new List<engineers>();
listeng.Add(new engineers { Name = profile.FirstName + " " + profile.LastName, Guid = GuidEngineer });
```

So far so good.

My question how can I pull the engineers name to the eng entry below:

```
 var tickets = from o in new HelpdeskEntities().Tickets.Where(t => t.TicketState.State == "Open")
                    select new AjaxTickets
                    {
                        TicketID = o.TicketID,
                        TicketSubject = o.TicketSubject,
                        ClientCompanyName = o.ClientCompany.ClientCompanyName,
                        DateOpened = o.DateOpened,
                        **eng** = list.Where(x => x.Guid == o.EngineerID).Select(x => new engineers {Guid = x.Guid, Name=x.Name }).FirstOrDefault().Name

                    };
```

I've also tried

```
var tickets = from o in new HelpdeskEntities().Tickets.Where(t => t.TicketState.State == "Open")
                    select new AjaxTickets
                    {
                        TicketID = o.TicketID,
                        TicketSubject = o.TicketSubject,
                        ClientCompanyName = o.ClientCompany.ClientCompanyName,
                        DateOpened = o.DateOpened,
                        **eng** = list.Where(x => x.Guid == o.EngineerID).Select(x => x.Name }).FirstOrDefault()
                    };
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Helpdesk2.ViewModel.engineers'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."}
```

Which I kinda of understand but cannot figure out away just to select the engineer name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot use your `list` in Linq-to-entities query. Only data existing in the database can be used. You cannot arbitrary combine linq-to-objects and linq-to-entities because EF doesn't know how to translate it to SQL. Use @harriyott's workaround and populate `Name` after you load tickets from the database.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to simplify the first one to:

```
list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Guid == o.EngineerID).Name
```

Having said that, Entity Framework probably won't let you run that when running a database call. If you can make a foreign key from ticket to engineer, then you can select it in the same way as you do the client company name. If not, then you'll need to do it in two goes: first, run the select without populating the engineer name property, and after that, fill them in with something like:

```
tickets.ForEach(ticket => ticket.EngineerName = engineers.First(eng => eng.Guid == ticket.EngineerID).Name)
```

Obviously you'll need to add the EngineerID property and select it in the first step.

Comment: The work around of filling in the name afterwords, is not well filling in the name.

Comment: It's very hard to test exactly what will happen without the actual code and database to run it against (hence why I wrote "something like"). Have you tried setting a breakpoint and examining what is in `tickets` and `engineers`?

Comment: OK, I had to send the results to a new varible then perform the work around