# Linq Query with Any() using in memory object and db

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Only primitive types (‘such as Int32, String, and Guid’) are supported in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539237/only-primitive-types-such-as-int32-string-and-guid-are-supported-in-this-c)

Ok so I have a user table  and a users_users table which basically just ties 2 users together.

My entityframework does not have a users_users in the Model, it only shows up as a relationship/property of the main user object. this relationship shows up as u.user1

so u.user1 is a collection of users where they exist in the users_users table.
this is great but..

I am trying to create a query where I can select all users from a user table, and as well create a boolean variable (called added in code below) in the select clause that will show whether there is a record for the user_user connection.

I am getting the error "Unable to create a constant value of type Only primitive types"

I understand I cannot use a in memory object  with a Linq query when using the "Any()" command in the select so how would I go about doing this? I am new to LINQ.

```
using (myEntities entities = new myEntities())
        {
             Model.user u = entities.users.Single(m => m.emailLogon == System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
             ObjectQuery<Model.user> susers = entities.users;

            var pplquery = (from suser in susers
                            select new { userId = suser.IdUser, FirstName = suser.contactinfo.FirstName, LastName = suser.contactinfo.LastName, added = 
                                u.user1.Any(cusr => cusr.IdUser == suser.IdUser)}).Take(15);


        }
```

Comment: -1 Please search SO for [appropriate fragments of] the [full] error message: e.g. [tag:linq only primitive types are supported](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tag%3Alinq+only+primitive+types+are+supported&submit=search). There are many duplicates. It doesn't matter if it's Any or Contains or ..

Comment: I have my doubts if one who "spent hours" reading the top results on that search link would *not* have an idea of what the problem is and how to fix it ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539237/only-primitive-types-such-as-int32-string-and-guid-are-supported-in-this-c , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654822/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-only-primitive-types-are-supported , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894715/entity-framework-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-x-only-primitive-t

Comment: Your comments are unhelpful and your attitude sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (myEntities entities = new myEntities())
        {
             Model.user u = entities.users.Single(m => m.emailLogon == System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
             var susers = entities.users.ToList();

            var pplquery = (from suser in susers.AsQueryable()
                            select new { userId = suser.IdUser, FirstName = suser.contactinfo.FirstName, LastName = suser.contactinfo.LastName, added = 
                                u.user1.Any(cusr => cusr.IdUser == suser.IdUser)}).Take(15);


        }
```

Turn it into a list to execute the query, then you can create new objects selecting from that set.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I was hoping it would be that easy!